# ListView Items are not appearing

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview where i am binding the its item source from the view model, while debugging at list in view model the list is showing the values but at emulator no values are appearing.

```
   <ListView x:Name="RegisteredUserList" ItemsSource="{Binding RegisteredUsers}" ItemSelected="RegisteredUserList_SelectedItemClicked" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding }" TextColor="Black" FontSize="13" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

My ViewModel code is:

```
   private async void GetAllUsersFromServer()
    {
        var registeredPeople =await UserService.Instance.GetAllUsers();
        foreach (var names in registeredPeople)
        {
            RegisteredUsers.Add(names.UserName);
        }
    }
```

`public List<string> RegisteredUsers
{
    get { return _regesteredUsers; }
    set
    {
        _regesteredUsers = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}`

`private List<string> _regesteredUsers= new   List<string>();`

At `RegisteredUsers` it is showing list of names but the UI is giving the values.How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only replace below ViewModel code remain rest of it

```
private async void GetAllUsersFromServer()
    {
        List<string> tmpRegisteredUsers = new List<string>();
        var registeredPeople =await UserService.Instance.GetAllUsers();
        foreach (var names in registeredPeople)
        {
            tmpRegisteredUsers.Add(names.UserName);
        }
        RegisteredUsers = tmpRegisteredUsers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RegisteredUsers property has to declared and instanciated like that in order to notify UI on any change (add, delete, move) :

```
ObservableCollection<string> RegisteredUser = new ObservableCollection();
```

For more information on this type, see https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/

Comment: Thanks for replay@Rudy,but it doesnt worked for me,i also tried `        public List<string> RegisteredUsers
        {
            get { return _regesteredUsers; }
            set
            {
                _regesteredUsers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }` but no change,Appearing only the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST use ObservableCollection if you want to add items.
With a List calling OnPropertyChanged. UI will be notified only when you initialize it (and when it is empty). An ObservableCollection will notify UI on each change.

Also, how/where do you set the BindingContext of the view?
It shoud be done in xaml or Code Behind using viewName.BindingContext = viewModelInstance;